# Left Join with between statement in access 2013

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have been facing problem in querying data in access 2013. I have tried to display all course name from the course table and shows the total no of students enrolled in each course from table called course enrolled between two dates provided by users. The problem is that query does not display all courses present in course table. it only shows course in which students are enrolled. Here is my SQL:

```
SELECT Course.Course_name, Count(new_enrolments.Student_code) AS Total,                 
Format([Start_date],"mmmm yyyy") AS [Month]
FROM Course LEFT JOIN new_enrolments ON Course.Course_name =  new_enrolments.Course_name
GROUP BY Course.Course_name, Format([Start_date],"mmmm yyyy"), new_enrolments.Start_date
HAVING (((new_enrolments.Start_date) Between [Forms]![ParameterForm]![txtBeginDate] And [Forms]![ParameterForm]![txtEndDate]));
```

Comment: What are control values for txtBeginDate and txtEndDate? You might need to wrap them in "#" tags and maybe even use CDate to convert them to Date fields you can use

Comment: txtBeginDate and txtEndDate format is shortDate.

Answer (score 1):

An **OUTER JOIN** (Left join or right join) works fine as long as you don't have a **WHERE CLAUSE** outside your join.
Because your where clause will be executed first, effectively turning your outer join into an **INNER JOIN**.
So the solution is to move your **WHERE CLAUSE** into your JOIN.
Below query should work:

```
SELECT a.Course_name, COUNT(b.Student_code) AS [Total],  Format(b.Start_date,"mmmm yyyy") AS [Month]
FROM Course a
LEFT JOIN 
(
SELECT b.Course_name, b.Student_code, b.Start_date 
FROM new_enrolments b
WHERE b.Start_date BETWEEN [Forms]![ParameterForm]![txtBeginDate] AND [Forms]![ParameterForm]![txtEndDate]
) b
ON a.Course_name=b.Course_name
GROUP BY a.Course_name, b.Start_date
;
```

Alternative is to use an **UNION** (see below).
The first query retrieves all course names for which enrollments exist.
The second one retrieves all course names for which no enrollments exist.

```
SELECT a.Course_name, COUNT(b.Student_code) AS [Total], Format(b.Start_date,"mmmm yyyy") AS [Month]
FROM Course a INNER JOIN new_enrolments b ON a.Course_name=b.Course_name
WHERE b.Start_date BETWEEN [Forms]![ParameterForm]![txtBeginDate] AND [Forms]![ParameterForm]![txtEndDate]
GROUP BY a.Course_name, b.Start_date
UNION
SELECT a.Course_name, NULL, NULL
FROM Course a
WHERE a.Course_name NOT IN
(
SELECT b.Course_name
FROM new_enrolments b
WHERE b.Start_date BETWEEN [Forms]![ParameterForm]![txtBeginDate] AND [Forms]![ParameterForm]![txtEndDate]
)
```